# Bounds for tolerance interval of non-normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

For the sake of Monte-Carlo simulations, I was asked to generate non-normal random variable $X$ (with pdf $f(x)$) displaying properties similar to standard normal variable, that is:

1. $f(x) = f(-x)$ (symmetry of pdf)
2. $f'(x) = -f'(-x), f'(x)>0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{-}$ (antisymmetry of pdf's derivative)
3. $EX = 0, \ EX^2 = 1$ (normalized in respect to mean and variance)

However, we want it to be much more 'spread' across the $x$ axis in the sense that: 
$$
\int_{-100}^{100}f(x) dx = 0.95
$$
(the bounds of tolerance interval for $N(0,1)$ are $(-1.96, 1.96)$). By applying g-and-h Tukey transformations, I have achieved the value of mere 2.009 ($g=0, h = 0.11$). It seems to me that such $f(x)$ does not exist, and the unit variance is to blame here. I have tried writing down variants of the system above, to no avail. Could you perhaps give me a hint or point towards some paper on the subject? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We demand

$$P(|X| < 100)=\int_{-100}^{100}f(x) dx = 0.95 \implies P(|X| \ge 100)=0.05.$$

But, by Tchebychev inequality :

$$P(|X| \ge 100) \le \frac 1 {{100}^2}.$$

Then having $X$ with these properties is impossible.

Comment: Jeez, you're right! What a fool I am! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Btw, are you aware of any stronger results for the RVs of the above type?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. But if $X$ has an even density $f$, then $E(X)=0$. If $f$ is also differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^*$, then the derivative is odd. So in fact you are just looking for a r.v. having a even and differentiable density on $\mathbb{R}^*$ with variance being $1$.    @Maria

Comment: Yes, I know that :) What I'm saying is that Chebyshev's equality is a general result with no saying of the pdf, so the bounds are usually considered loose. Are there stronger results for the bounds, provided pdf has properties 1-2 formulated above?

Comment: Hah, turns out there are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Unimodal_symmetrical_distributions

Comment: Yes indeed there are, but they have more hypothesis than you do.